# Specify "Number of decimal places" for my Currency site column, will not prevent users for adding extra decimal numbers

Tags: 2013, javascript, development, list-form, site-column

I am working on a team site collection inside my on-premises farm 2013. and i created a site column of type Currency which have "Number of decimal places" = 2, as follow:-

[image]

but when i try adding or editing items using the built-in list forms, i can enter extra decimal places inside the above site column as follow, without getting any warning or any error:-

[image]

the only thing the "Number of decimal places" will have effect on, it that when i save the item, the system will trim extra decimal numbers by doing some rounding. currently if i enter `10.12345` it will be saved as `10.12`, while if i enter `5.7999` it will be saved as `5.80`. so is there a way i can prevent users from adding more than 2 decimal places ??

Answer (score 2):

That is how the number of decimal spaces works. You could use a JSLink to apply validation (causing a notification that more than 2 decimals is not allowed).

This should show an error on clicking save and wait for acceptable input... Totally untested, but it's where I'd start.

The regex allows $ (change to symbol of your choice) but does not require, allows commas every 3 digits (not required), allows 2 decimals (or none, or one). There may be some validations that are valid but missed (I found the regex at [RegexLib](http://www.regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=2&categoryId=3&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)). This could be changed to look at keystrokes and validate as typing occurs, but I'll leave that for someone else.

Save this file somewhere (I use a folder in _catalogs/masterpage), check it in and on the form settings link with JSLink.

```
// List add and edit - Decimal Place Validation

(function () { 

    // Create object that have the context information about the field that we want to change it's output render  
    var monthlyCostFieldContext = {}; 
    monthlyCostFieldContext.Templates = {}; 
    monthlyCostFieldContext.Templates.Fields = { 
        // Apply the new rendering for Monthly Recurring Cost field on New and Edit Forms 
        "Monthly Recurring Cost": { 
            "NewForm": monthlyCostFieldTemplate, 
            "EditForm":  monthlyCostFieldTemplate 
        } 
    }; 

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(monthlyCostFieldContext); 

})(); 

// This function provides the rendering logic 
function monthlyCostFieldTemplate(ctx) { 

    var formCtx = SPClientTemplates.Utility.GetFormContextForCurrentField(ctx); 

    // Register a callback just before submit. 
    formCtx.registerGetValueCallback(formCtx.fieldName, function () { 
        return document.getElementById('inpCost').value; 
    }); 

    //Create container for various validations 
    var validators = new SPClientForms.ClientValidation.ValidatorSet(); 
    validators.RegisterValidator(new decimalValidator()); 

    // Validation failure handler. 
    formCtx.registerValidationErrorCallback(formCtx.fieldName, decimalOnError); 

    formCtx.registerClientValidator(formCtx.fieldName, validators); 

    return " \ 
            
"; 
} 

// Custom validation object to validate email format 
decimalValidator = function () { 
    decimalValidator.prototype.Validate = function (value) { 
        var isError = false; 
        var errorMessage = ""; 

        //decimal format Regex expression 
        var decimalRegex = /^(\$|)([1-9]\d{0,2}(\,\d{3})*|([1-9]\d*))(\.\d{2})?$/; 

        if (!decimalRegex.test(value.toString()) && value.toString().trim()) { 
            isError = true; 
            errorMessage = "Invalid amount entered"; 
        } 

        //Send error message to error callback function (decimalOnError) 
        return new SPClientForms.ClientValidation.ValidationResult(isError, errorMessage); 
    }; 
}; 

// Add error message to spnError element under the input field element 
function decimalOnError(error) { 
    document.getElementById("spnError").innerHTML = "" + error.errorMessage + ""; 
}
```

**A simpler idea is to put a description on the column that will notify users that anything beyond 2 decimals will be rounded.**